# Wait for server response in Jena custom PropertyFunction

Tags: java, server, client, wait, jena

A bit of background: `PropertyFunction` is an [interface in Jena API](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/pfunction/PropertyFunction.html) that allows doing performing custom operations using SPARQL syntax. Example:

```
select ?result { ?result f:myPropertyFunction 'someObject' . }
```

So I made a class `Launch` that implements this interface and extends a class `Client`. Within the body of the `exec` method of my `Launch` class I establish a connection to a server and, while sending information is no problem, waiting for the server to respond is. Whenever I try to `wait()` for server response I get the following exception: `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Here is the body of my `exec` method for reference:

```
QueryIterator it = null;

try {
    this.connect();    // works well

    this.send(algorithmAndArgs);    // works well

    this.wait();    // exception is thrown

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    ResultSet rs = ResultSetFactory.create(it, Arrays.asList(resultIdentifiers));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return it;
```

Anyone know what the problem may be? Thank you for your answer.

**EDIT 1:** One thing that I forgot to mention is that the `Client` class has a method called `onObjectReceived(Object o, Socket s)` that is triggered each time something is received from the server. I tried using a `isDone` variable with a `while` loop in the `exec` method and set it to true once an object is received, but it did not work.

Comment: `this.wait` is a Java language operation and the code needs to be holding the objects  a object monitor (synchronized lock). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem: I created an attribute `private final CountDownLatch objectWasReceivedLatch = new CountDownLatch(1)` and, in the `exec` method I do `boolean objectWasReceived = objectWasReceivedLatch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` when I want to wait for a response; in the `onObjectReceived` method I call `objectWasReceivedLatch.countDown()`.